# mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in

Tags: php, mysql

I have come across new errors

mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login\check_login.php on line 12
Database name is not available!

mysql_select_db('localhost', 'test')or die("Database name is not available!");

Comment: need to pass connection object of mysql

Comment: When will people start reading the documentation of the tools they use if they run into issues? It answers your question immediately: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: also use mysqli in place of mysql...

Comment: Apart from that: stop using the old, outdated and deprecated mysql extension, use the new and better mysqli extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// Change database to "test"
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```